# eclipse recovering from crash

Tags: java, eclipse, crash

I had eclipse open when my computer crashed - now I've restarted and there are various errors in my project.  It appears as if some files do not contain recently made changes.  I am quite sure I saved everything before the crash.  Does anyone know the best way to recover?

Comment: This is why it is a good idea to use version control, and checkin frequently ...

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove org.eclipse.core.resources from your workspace:

```
cd ~/Documents/workspace/.metalog/.plugins
rm -rf  org.eclipse.core.resources
```

By removing **org.eclipse.core.resources**, you clear out all the project metadata from your workspace. However, don’t worry, once you start eclipse you can just go to “File -> Import -> import eclipse projects” and re-import all your workspace projects.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need to refresh each of your projects (select them in the Project Explorer and hit <kbd>F5</kbd>) and then clean and build them.

If your source files truly lost work it's probably because you didn't save them (most likely) or there's some bug with Eclipse or one of its plugins (far less likely).

Answer (score 1):

Refresh your whole workspace and rebuild the projects.

Then compare your workspace to the files in the source repository to see what changes you have.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to start eclipse once from the command line with the -clean option.