# Recover lost Java source code due to previous abnormal exit of eclipse

Tags: eclipse

My java code which almost spanned 3000 lines was open on Eclipse code window as I was working on that. Suddenly my PC froze and I had to restart it. Later when I opened eclipse it threw some error saying some org.eclipse... file was corrupt, dint bother to write it down, my fault :(
But later it showed "could not read metadata for workspace dir.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.root.indexes\properties.index" in my java code file.
I restarted eclipse to get rid of the error, but the result was disastrous; the java code file was empty. My worry is, after my last backup, I had done a lot of changes to it here n there.

Finally I could figure it out. jst need to compare with local history :P

Comment: You have my sympathy, but that's why God invented auto-save

Comment: That's why you have Ctrl + S, you need to keep on pressing this even after small change :)

Comment: ctrl+s wont help when u exit eclipse abnormally it jst erases all contents. absurd!

Comment: @JohnySmith, at-least you will get data till last saved, it's better instead of loosing all code right?

Comment: Eclipse, by default, stores the file history quite regularly. (There should be a "view previous versions" or similar.. although it has been years since I've had to use Eclipse.) Also, now might be a good time to invest in a real SCM vs "last backup" :D

Comment: Commit early and commit often

Comment: @PradeepSimha pls go thru my question once again if u've not got it.. and the prob is not due to not saving(and i did save it at last as well) Oh god i'm tired of explainin u. forget it.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion @pst. bt i still prefer my ususal backup :P

Answer (score 32):

Am not sure if this will work but you can give these 2 methods a try:

1. Right click file-->Team-->Show local history (Try to look for the file in "history view")

If this fails,try
2. Manually go to "Eclipse workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.history"
You can find a list of folders named with few letters, use the “Date Modified” column and open the latest of those folders to get the recent files you were working on.
In that folder, you can find some files with unusual naming, open the files with some text editor to find the file you are searching for, if possible try to match the file size.

Let me know if this helps.
:)

Comment: Didn't work for me. An editor can't be forgiven when it reverts 45 minutes of work without prompting. So arrogant.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, Johny

I think you may find your code in your 'Local History'

Refer :

[How to recover Java file from Eclipse Project that damaged by getting power off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787737/how-to-recover-java-file-from-eclipse-project-that-damaged-by-getting-power-off)

[eclipse recovering from crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464557/eclipse-recovering-from-crash)

http://www.coderanch.com/t/473927/vc/recover-java-File-Deleted-Eclipse